# Nexus 3.5.0-02 PyPi Missing simple URL?

Tags: pip, nexus, pypi, nexus3

[Documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/pypi.html) shows these options for pip.conf:

```
[global]
index = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi-all/pypi
index-url = http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi-all/simple
```

But in our OSS 3 nexus no such URL's are available and we can't find any python distributions. Must be missing something here.

```
twine upload-r nexus
```

Is working fine.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out i'm having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the group url vs hosted/internal

http://nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/simple/